# WebStorm watcher output path

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to set up a Typescript project in WebStorm where the files are transpiled to a dist-folder.

My project folder structure:

```
projectroot/src/subfolder/subfolder/index.ts
```

and I want the files to be placed like this:

```
projectroot/dist/subfolder/subfolder/index.js
```

My output path in WebStorm:

```
$FileDir$/../dist/
```

But the files doesn't retain the subfolder structure and the files land in

```
projectroot/dist/index.js
```

How can I get make it add the subfolder structure?

Comment: It's recommended to use a [built-in TypeScript compiler](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/03/how-to-compile-typescript-in-webstorm/)
 in WebStorm instead of a file watcher. You can specify the compiler options including the output directory in a [tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file.

Answer (score 0):

To access the project root, use `$ProjectFileDir$` and `$FileDirPathFromParent$`

```
$ProjectFileDir$/dist/$FileDirPathFromParent(less)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js
```

You need to test it though, couldn't test it on this computer.